Conversion from wood stud hardware to metal stud/toggle bolts?
I currently am looking to install some shelf mounts that come with #10x1.8 in screws to drill into wood studs. Two mounts have a 55 lb weight capacity. Our walls have metal studs, so I need to use toggle bolts instead. Is there a conversion from one to the other; i.e. what size toggle bolts are appropriate?

Depending on what you are doing, sheet metal screws into holes drilled in the metal studs may be a better answer than toggle bolts.
